# attach and open a userguide style pdf to a vb project

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, pdf, resources

Hi all I have created a windows form in visual studio, and have put together a user guide saved as a PDF. I Would like the end user to be able to open this from the windows form menu bar.

I have added the PDF to the resources folder of my project but cant figure out how to open it up from here, or how it would be addressed when installed and I don't necessarily know the full file path.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using `System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` you can get the base directory of your executable.

So you can use this code to open your PDF file using default application:

```
Process.Start( _
    IO.Path.Combine(
        System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, _
        "your_resources_folder", _
        "your_pdf_file.pdf"
    )
)
```

Please note that your executable debug is created in `\bin\debug` folder of your project; so it is better use:

```
Process.Start( _
    IO.Path.Combine(
        IIf(Not Debugger.IsAttached, _
            System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, _
            Strings.Replace(UCase(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory), UCase("\bin\debug\"), "") _
        ), _
        "your_resources_folder", _
        "your_pdf_file.pdf"
    )
)
```